# Fatal error: Call to a member function isVirtual() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

We are facing fatal error in the cart page:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isVirtual() on a non-object in `return $this->getConfig()->isEnabled() && !$this->getProduct()->isVirtual();`

Full code : `app/code/community/WebDevlopers/ProductPageShipping/Block/Estimate/Abstract.php`

```
<?php
abstract class WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Block_Estimate_Abstract extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{

    protected $_estimate = null;



    protected $_config = null;



    protected $_session = null;


    protected $_carriers = null;


    public function getEstimate()
    {
        if ($this->_estimate === null) {
            $this->_estimate = Mage::getSingleton('webdevlopers_productpageshipping/estimate');
        }

        return $this->_estimate;
    }


    public function getConfig()
    {
        if ($this->_config === null) {
            $this->_config = Mage::getSingleton('webdevlopers_productpageshipping/config');
        }

        return $this->_config;
    }


    public function getSession()
    {
        if ($this->_session === null) {
            $this->_session = Mage::getSingleton('webdevlopers_productpageshipping/session');
        }

        return $this->_session;
    }


    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->getConfig()->isEnabled() && !$this->getProduct()->isVirtual();
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, is this your own extension? If so, what context are you calling the block in? Because it extends from a Product block, you should always be able to call `$this->getProduct()` without it returning false/null. A quick win would be `return $this->getConfig()->isEnabled() && $this->getProduct() && !$this->getProduct()->isVirtual();` a la check `getProduct()` returns a truthy before using it

Comment: @RobbieAverill This is not my extension . can you please tell me what code i need to replace with `return $this->getConfig()->isEnabled() && !$this->getProduct()->isVirtual();`

Comment: The code I just gave you :) talk to whoever wrote the extension, and get them to fix it. If you'd like, I can explain how you can make a *local* model override to keep you from hacking up a community class, but make sure the change works first otherwise it's not worth doing

Comment: @RobbieAverill this is [extension](https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/Magento%20Display%20Shipping%20estimation%20Block%20in%20Product%20view%20page)

i didt got reply from devoloper. actually i did't understood this : "check `getProduct()` returns a truthy before using it" 

can you please give updated code to check it.

Comment: Mate - copy and paste the code in my comment, and replace your broken code with it, then run your script. I gave you a full example.

Comment: fantastic, sorry i did't observerd your comment. can you please post as an asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that your model extends from a Product model, the `getProduct()` method should be valid. You may be using it outside of the regular Magento product view context which may be causing this error.

You should check that the product exists before trying to use it:

```
return $this->getConfig()->isEnabled() && $this->getProduct() && !$this->getProduct()->isVirtual();
```

To avoid modifying community code, you should extend this class into the local pool and make the change in a local class.

I've submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/pull/4) to the main repository to get this fixed for future. It's a harmless change for regular use, so wouldn't hurt to have it in there.